# jstree: cannot change icon by changing 'rel' attribute in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I load a jsTree from json data, and change each node's icon every 10 seconds by changing its `rel` attribute.

I define some type:

```js
"state1": {
    "icon": {
        "image": "../Content/images/state1.png"
    }
},
"state2": {
    "icon": {
        "image": "../Content/images/state2.png"
    }
}
```

I change `rel` so that icon can change :

```cs
 $("#leaf").attr("rel", "state2");
```

It works well in FireFox, but does not work in IE : with IE it only works when mouse is over the body or when scrolling.

I use jsTree 1.0-rc3.